# How to interpret different behavior of sleep and wait when they are interrupted

Tags: signals, shell-builtin

I'm trying to understand the subtleties between `sleep` and `sleep & wait`.

1. If run the script `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10000
```

in one terminal and `ps -aef --forest` in another terminal, then I see

```
myuser   14355   14113  0 23:26 pts/5    00:00:00  |           \_ /bin/bash ./test.sh
myuser   14356   14355  0 23:26 pts/5    00:00:00  |               \_ sleep 10000
```

If I send interrupt to `sleep` process (`kill -INT 14356`), then both `bash` and `sleep` processes end.

2. If the last line in `test.sh` is instead

```
sleep 10000 & wait
```

and I run `ps` again, I see

```
myuser   14381   14113  0 23:31 pts/5    00:00:00  |           \_ /bin/bash ./test.sh
myuser   14382   14381  0 23:31 pts/5    00:00:00  |               \_ sleep 10000
```

If I send interrupt to `sleep` again, then nothing happens. However, I can terminate `bash` process now.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/trap.html says that

> When a subshell is entered, traps that are not being ignored are set to the default actions.

It seems to me that default actions for sleep is to terminate when interrupted (if I plainly run `sleep 10000` in one terminal and then try to interrupt it from another terminal, it terminates).

Why can't I interrupt `sleep` directly in 2 but I can in 1?

Comment: Sleep and wait have nothing to do with one another AT ALL. Your question appears to be about something else, namely why these two behave differently to interrupts, I suppose.

Comment: @RichardT  you are right, I adjusted the title.